# Erro in option add_overall of tbl_summary

Tags: gtsummary

Some times, when I try make table whith tbl_summary function and put de add_ overall() argument occurred the error below:

Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1`  and `..2` .
x Some attributes are incompatible.
i The author of the class should implement vctrs methods.
i See https://vctrs.r-lib.org/reference/faq-error-incompatible-attributes.html.

HELP ME

Comment: please share your code and data that is creating this error in you question